# How to remotely collecting analytical data from a locally hosted web app

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, google-analytics, analytics

I am building a web app that runs on a Raspberry Pi/PC that allows a user to control equipment from a remote browser. To get a better understanding of our users we would like to have an option where users can collect and send usage data back to us. Very similar to Google Analytics.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, is there some kind of system currently available that will do this?

The web-app is currently written in python but I am looking at moving over to Node.JS in the future.

(The system will not be connected to the internet at all time.)

Comment: What kind of usage data? Where they are from and how much they stay in the page or what buttons they click most, or which pages do they stay in the most time?

Comment: DOM events like number of clicks. Error logs would be very helpful.

Comment: In what intervals will the system be connected to the internet ? With the Measurement Protocol in GA you can set an offset ("queue time") of up to 4 hours.

Comment: I think it would be wise to first focus on the users that are always on-line. This makes me wonder, does our app fall into the mobile app category and will we be able to use GA mobile app tracking?

Comment: @BertusKruger, that's for you to decide - you can use GAs "Measurement Protocol" (which is language- and device-agnostic) and decide for yourself if it makes more sense to send along web or app dimensions and metrics (you have to set up the property you're tracking to accordingly).